# SharePoint 2010's webpart

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to create a webpart with some custom properties. They are personalization properties.
But when I logged-in by normal user who have "contributor" permission and I see that the normal user cannot change the value of custom properties.

Is there anyone can let me know that what user can change the webpart's custom properties.
Or, which code snippet can make the custom properties can change by every user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-sharepoint-services-help/permission-levels-and-permissions-HA010100149.aspx

The custom properties you are talking about is not directly tied to any permission. Instead, its tied to the permission of the site in which the page containing the web part is hosted. If you have the design rights on the site, you can update the web part properties. Contributors by default, do not have the design rights.

If you want , you can modify the contributors permission level to include design rights at the site level.

Comment: Thanks, This is different form sharepoint 2007, isn't it? I see that on sharepoint 2007 any user who can access to the page and view the page as "personal view" can update any custom properties.

Comment: No, when you see personal view, the properties are updated only for that user and not for all ....

Comment: But only user who have design rights can make a change to the custom properties on "shared view" or "personal view". Is that right?

Comment: By the way, is there any article of Microsoft talking about this issue. I need to report to my boss.

Comment: Its not an issue, its how it is designed .. Why do you think its an issue ?

Comment: Oh, yes its not an issue. It's my misstate

Answer (score 0):

you have to make personalization scope to be of user scope not as shared one

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z36h8be9.aspx